# Difference between the sheet index, sheet name, and displayed sheet name

Tags: excel, vba, properties

I have been given a macro-enabled workbook with well over 100 sheets that I need to understand and document.  I have a piece of code that lists the index of the sheet and the name of the sheet.

```
Sub list_sheets()
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
         Dim i As Integer
         WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count
         For i = 1 To WS_Count
            Debug.Print i, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).name, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).SheetName
         Next i
End Sub
```

This produces output as follows:

```
 1            ReadMe
 2            TableOfContents
 3            DATA
 ...
```

BUT on the Microsoft Excel Object panels it has names like

```
"Sheet1 (DATA)"
"Sheet2 (Manifest)"
```

I would expect the number on the sheet name to match the index, but that's okay.  If I can just get to the other name.

Note that if I check the properties for the sheet, then this other name is listed under the property
"(Name)" as opposed to "Name", i.e. distinguished by enclosing parentheses.  How can I get at that "(Name)" property in addition to the "Name" property?

Comment: A `Worksheet` doesn't have a `SheetName` property. You're looking for [`CodeName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.codename). The index (position) and name of a sheet can easily change. The codename, much less so.

Comment: That's it. Thanks